# Understanding scope with inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm testing my understanding of inheritance in C++ and was reading through some example code. Based on the program output, it seems to me that the `double add()` and `int add()` functions have different scope, and instead of calling the `double add()` function with argument **10.5**, there is an implicit type conversion from `double` to `int` (which is always truncated) and the function `int add()` is called instead. The type conversion would explain why the output is `11 11`.

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the scope of inherited functions that are overloaded?
2. When, if ever, is a type conversion from `double` to `int` invalid (i.e. would instead result in a compile-time error)?
3. Where can I read more about the nuances of namespaces/scope with inheritance in C++?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class One {
    public: 
        double add(double x) { return x + 0.1; } 
};

class Two : public One {
    public:
        int add(int x) { return x + 1; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Two obj;
    cout << obj.add(10) << " " << obj.add(10.5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do *you* think the answers are, and why?

Comment: For documentation involving scope, read the C++ standard draft or ISO standard, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf.

Comment: In your example, "double add()" and "int int()" are simply different functions from different classes.  [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) doesn't really play a role here - they're just completely unrelated to each other ;)

Comment: `double` always matches an `int` parameter, it can be invalid if the double is out of range but that is runtime UB (no diagnostic required)

Comment: @M.M By out of range, do you mean that the value of the `double` that is implicitly casted to `int` is greater than INT_MAX?

Comment: @Raymond Does this cover C++14? Also, can you recommend any other specifications for C++ that are beginner friendly? I'm just now beginning to read about C++ (A Tour of C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup and Effective C++ by Scott Meyers)

Comment: @dereferencednullptr Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/.

Comment: @dereferencednullptr roughly, yes, although the boundary condition is a bit weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of `add` as `int add(int x) { return x + 1; }`  hides any other definitions of `add` from outer scopes,  this is the same behaviour as shadowing of variables in nested blocks in a function.

Name lookup always finds a name in a scope before going on to potential overload resolution amongst multiple occurrences of that name in the same scope; `obj.add(10.5)` finds `Two::add()` and so does not go on to check outer scopes.

You can redeclare the functions from outer scopes in Two with `using One::add;`

On the conversion topic; a `double` argument always matches an `int` parameter. It can be invalid if the double is out of range for `int` but that is runtime undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required).

This topic is covered in [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#overload-derived)  , you could also check the Name Lookup article on cppreference.

Comment: What do you mean by the declaration of `add` hides other definitions in outer scopes? Is it correct to say that the declaration of `add` in the base class is hidden because of the derived declaration? If that's right, would it be correct to say that a `using` redeclaration allows the scope to be switched to the base (effectively allowing the outer scope to be "seen")?

Comment: I added another function in the base class that takes `char` as input, and then called all three functions from `main`. Is the using statement effectively the same as having all three function declarations in class `Two`?

Comment: "switched" is not something that scopes can do. `One` is a scope, `Two` is a different scope .  `using` (in this context) brings names declared in a different scope into the current scope .

Comment: @dereferencednullptr https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Answer (score 0):

Overloading does not work with inheritance in C++:

> Overloading doesn’t work for derived class in C++ programming
>   language. There is no overload resolution between Base and Derived.
>   The compiler looks into the scope of Derived, finds the single
>   function “double f(double)” and calls it. It never disturbs with the
>   (enclosing) scope of Base. In C++, there is no overloading across
>   scopes – derived class scopes are not an exception to this general
>   rule

The example they used had `double f(double)` in the derived class.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/does-overloading-work-with-inheritance/

To fix this, the class would have to be redesigned. I can't give any specific feedback as to how to change it as the class is very generic.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, I would like to add that you can avoid this issue of overloading by creating a **template** for `One::add()` which will allow it to accept both integers and doubles, and then let class `Two` inherite it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class One {
public:
    template <typename T>  //Template allows us to create a function template whose functionality can be adapted to more than one type or class without repeating the entire code for each type.
    double add(T x)
    {
        if (floor(x) == x) //Check if x is integer
            return x + 1;
        else              
        {
            return x + 0.1;
        }
    }
};

class Two : public One {
public:
    //No need for overloading add() here because in Class One, add() function will accept integers and doubles
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Two obj;
    cout << obj.add(10) << " " << obj.add(10.5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```